# VC++ 2013 std::move and rvalue compile error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am following [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/o0pCft99K74?list=PL1835A90FC78FF8BE)  on using C++ 11 threads.The following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

void theFun(std::promise<std::string> && prms)
{
  std::string str("Hellow from  future");
  prms.set_value(str); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::promise<std::string> prms;
  std::future<std::string> ftr = prms.get_future();

  std::thread tr(&theFun,std::move(prms));
  std::cout << "Hellow from main!" << std::endl;
  std::string str = ftr.get();//will block if thread still working

  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  tr.join();
}
```

works for the tutorial author.He is using VS2010 and some experiment implementation.But in my case I am getting the following error:

> \program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\functional(1149): error C2664: 'void (std::promise &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 
>   'std::promise' to 'std::promise &&' 1>
>   You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference

Does it mean VC2013 doesn't support Rvalue arguments?

Comment: Looks like a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180644/why-is-this-not-compiling-rvalue-as-thread-ctor-arguments

Comment: Yeah,looks like my question is a duplicate.But what's the workaround?

Comment: Ok,using std::ref for now solves it.The question can be closed.