# Subclassing std::thread and forwarding packed/variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, subclass, variadic, stdthread

In my code I would like to have all threads subclass from a type that in turn subclasses from std::thread. The reasons, which I'm sure are common:

1. A stop request from outside the thread, and continue check from inside the thread, are done the same way regardless of which type of thread it is. In other words each type of thread doesn't have its own stop/check logic.
2. The code that is run in a thread doesn't have to care if it's actually running in a thread or not, other than calling `thread::shouldBeRunning()` which always returns true if not within a thread.

However, there is a problem with (I think) how I'm passing the template parameters/values from the subclass of `std::thread` through to the wrapper function, which in the below code is `static void run(thread * This, Function&& Func, Args&&... a)`

```
    #include <thread>
    #include <atomic>
    #include <iostream>

    class thread
    {
        friend int main(int, char **);

    private:
        std::atomic<bool> m_ShouldBeRunning;
        std::atomic<bool> m_Running;
        int               m_Error;
        std::thread       m_Thread;

    #ifdef WIN32
        __declspec(thread) static thread * m_Local;
    #else
        __thread static thread * m_Local;
    #endif

        template <typename Function, typename... Args>
        static void run(thread * This, Function&& Func, Args&&... a)
        {
            thread::m_Local = This;

            try
            {
                std::bind(std::forward<Function>(Func), std::forward<Args>(a)...)();
            }
            catch (int Error)
            {
                This->m_Error = Error;
            }
            This->m_Running.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        }

    public:

        template <typename Function, typename... Args>
        thread(Function&& Func, Args&&... a)
            : m_ShouldBeRunning(true)
            , m_Running(true)
            , m_Error(0)
            , m_Thread(&thread::run<Function, Args...>,
                        this,
                        std::forward<Function>(Func),
                        std::forward<Args>(a)...)
        {}
        virtual ~thread()
        {
            try
            {
                stop();
                m_Thread.join();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                std::cerr << "caught exception in ~thread!";
            }
        }

        bool isRunning() const { return m_Running.load(std::memory_order_acquire); }

        static thread * get() { return thread::m_Local; }

        static bool shouldBeRunning()
        {
            thread * Thread = thread::m_Local;
            return (Thread)
                ? Thread->m_ShouldBeRunning.load(std::memory_order_acquire)
                : true;
        }

        void stop() { m_ShouldBeRunning.store(false, std::memory_order_release); }
    };

    thread * thread::m_Local = NULL;

    class doStuff
    {
    private:
        int   m_X;
        float m_Y;
        char  m_Z;

    public:
        doStuff(int X, float Y, char Z)
            : m_X(X), m_Y(Y), m_Z(Z) {}

        void stuff(int X, float Y, char Z)
        {
            while (thread::shouldBeRunning())
            {
                std::cout << (X + m_X) << " " << (Y + m_Y) << " " << Z << m_Z << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
        }
    };

    class threadDoStuff : public thread
    {
    public:
        threadDoStuff(doStuff & Stuff, int X, float Y, char Z)
            : thread(&doStuff::stuff,
                         &Stuff,
                         X,
                         Y,
                         Z)
        {}
    };

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        doStuff stuff(3, 2.0f, 'z');
        threadDoStuff stuffThread(stuff, 5, 1.0f, 'a');

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        return 0;
    }
```

MSVC 2013 spits out a long error chain, the top of which is:

```
------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  main.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1149): error C2664: 'void (thread *,Function &&,doStuff *&&,int &,float &,char &)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'doStuff *' to 'doStuff *&&'
          with
          [
              Function=void (__thiscall doStuff::* )(int,float,char)
          ]
          You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Comment: With `&thread::run<Function, Args...>`, you no longer use forwarding reference and force to pass lvalue/rvalue reference to it.

Comment: Use `m_Thread(&thread::run<std::decay_t<Function>, std::decay_t<Args>...>,` instead

Comment: Ok, I get how that causes a difference between how the function is defined and how it's called, but doing that then causes `error C2664: 'void (thread *,Function &&,doStuff *&&,int &&,float &&,char &&)' : cannot convert argument 6 from 'char' to 'char &&'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jarod42 and Piotr for providing part of the resolution, but my issue was ultimately resolved by upgrading to MSVC 2015. According to [some comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180644/why-is-this-not-compiling-rvalue-as-thread-ctor-arguments), earlier versions of MSVC had issues dealing with `std::thread` constructor parameters. While I would have upgraded anyway, I would like to have figured out the problem without upgrading, but it was taking too much time. Also I haven't run the code yet, but at least it compiles.

TLDR - I didn't figure out the cause but it might be due to MSVC, as upgrading fixed it.